# Why does this query return values?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am starting to learn SQL and I had a question.
I am running the following query:

```
SELECT ProductName 
FROM Products
WHERE ProductID =ALL (
       SELECT ProductID 
       FROM OrderDetails 
       WHERE Quantity < 0
)
order by ProductID;
```

Why does this query return values if I am looking for quantity less than zero?
In the OrderDetails table, there are no quantity less than zero. So shouldn't the output of this query be empty?
Is there something I am missing.

[w3schools SQL Practice](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_any&ss=-1)

Comment: Are you sure it does? Doesn't it give an error? Does it return without error in mySQL?

Comment: This code is different than the linked example -- in the linked example it has "ANY" not "ALL".  If you change the example to ALL it gives no results

Comment: Can you share more details, like sample data?

Comment: The database that you are using is Access and not MySql.

Comment: @forpas -- why do you say that?  That makes no sense.

Comment: @Hogan go to the link where DiMaria tries the code and run `select version()`

Comment: As a side note here -- If you are learning SQL w3schools is a bad place to do so.  Please ignore this results and find a better website.  ANY, ALL and such are not useful to a beginner since they are platform specific and are not used often.  Bad place to start TBH

Comment: @DiMaria, you tagged this question mysql, can you please clarify if you are trying to use MySQL? Keep in mind implementation of SQL is different in each brand of database.

Comment: @forpas -- it gave me an error :(

Comment: @Hogan because it is not MySql. It is Access.

Comment: @forpas -- once again w3schools makes our lives miserable.

Answer (score 1):

If your subquery has a WHERE clause that is always false, then the subquery returns an empty result.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/all-subqueries.html says:

> Finally, the expression is TRUE if table t2 is empty. So, the
> following expression is TRUE when table t2 is empty:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE 1 > ALL (SELECT s1 FROM t2);
> ```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/zCO71Q15

An ALL predicate means it's false if at least one row of the subquery causes the comparison to be false.

But if the subquery returns zero rows, then of course there can't be any rows that cause the predicate to be false.

Comment: How this relates to = ALL ( ... )? I expect it to give an error and you are saying it would work without an error?

Comment: @CetinBasoz I added a demo link. Go ahead and try it.

Comment: I see. I never used ALL and now it makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Is it any clearer written as

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM Products p
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL 
    FROM OrderDetails o
    WHERE o.ProductID = p.ProductId
        AND o.Quantity = 10
 );
```

I.e., find all products where an order has been placed for exactly 10 of them.

Comment: This is wrong, this is not how ALL works.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/all-subqueries.html